# Cleaner and better way to select and change colour of circles in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

After playing around a lot I managed to make the following function change the colour of all 7 of my circles at once. There is a variable colors that is an array of strings of colours.

Here is my function:

```
function colorSquares(){
    for(let i = 0; i<7 ; i++){
        let id = '#s' + i ;
        d3.select(id).attr('fill',colors[i]);
     }
}
```

I cannot help but think there is a much easier way of doing this! I created the 7 circles like this:

```
for(let i = 0 ; i< 7; i++){
    const circle = d3.select('.canvas')
        .append('circle')
            .attr('cx', 70 + i* 50)
            .attr('cy', 100)
            .attr('r', 20)
            .attr('stroke' ,'grey')
            .attr('stroke-width', 5)
            .attr('id' , 'c'+i );

}
```

As you can see I manually made a string and added it using .attr to each circle and then mess around with strings to call this circle later. Does anyone have a cleaner and better way to do this, effectively I am looking for better ways to create and then select circles such that I don't have to botch strings as ID's

Comment: You should also be using selectAll to create all the circles as well - D3 is generally designed to avoid loops for creating or updating: `var circles = d3.select('.canvas').selectAll("circle").data(d3.range(7)).enter().append("circle").attr("cx", d=> 70 + i * 50....` Then you can reuse the circles variable to change them later, rather than selecting them again.

Comment: @AndrewReid thanks andrew! I just managed to make that work and saved about 10 lines of code :)

Comment: is there any advantage to using var circles = as opposed to const circles = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
d3.select('.canvas')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .attr('fill', (d, i) => colors[i]);
```

Comment: This worked great! Could you explain why we need (d, i) => colors[i]). When I tried just  i => colors[i]) it doesnt work :)

Comment: Because the first argument is the current datum (d by convention), and the second argument is the current index (i by convention): see https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr